# AngularJS app unusably slow on IE9 unless developer tools enabled

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have developed a website using AngularJS for a client of ours. This is a very basic use of Angular: we use a couple of directives to create a form (with validation), post it to the backend using JSON and display the results.

The main stakeholder in this project has been complaining that the site is too slow. When I went to his desk to check everything seemed fine, until I closed developer tools. Suddenly IE slowed down immensly (almost to the point of crashing). I know it's not a lingering `console.log()`, as the site works but is just unreasonably slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a JavaScript profiler to identify what part of your code is the bottleneck.

Even if the app runs fine when the developer tools are open, you should be able to identify the culprit and then analyze that part (function, probably) to find the issue.

You can even come back on Stack Overflow with that specific issue.

Without additional information, we can't do much more.

**Also**, if I were you, I would run the same JS profiling on IE10, FF and Chrome too.
Chances are that the same code can be *heavy* on other browsers too.